# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED] when running npm run start

Tags: node.js, npm, apache-age

I have cloned and setup the apache age viewer but now when i want to run it by executing the command `npm run start` it gives me the following error.

```
> ag-viewer-backend@0.4.0 start /home/shaheen/Desktop/Demo/age-viewer/backend
> babel-node src/bin/www


> ag-viewer-frontend@0.1.0 start /home/shaheen/Desktop/Demo/age-viewer/frontend
> react-scripts start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:438
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './v4' is not defined by "exports" in /home/shaheen/Desktop/Demo/age-viewer/frontend/node_modules/uuid/package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:513:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shaheen/Desktop/Demo/age-viewer/frontend/node_modules/webpack-log/src/index.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this error. Can anyone provide guidance on what might be going wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try to remove `node_modules` and install again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `node_modules` folder from the `frontend` folder then run:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Then run `npm run setup` again to install the required packages.

Also make sure that you are working with the recommended node version that is mentioned in the `age-viewer` documentation which is `^14.16.0`.
You can check [AGE-Viewer documentation](https://github.com/apache/age-viewer) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the **uuid** package that the Apache Age-Viewer is using.

In your age-viewer directory, try running the following:

```
rm -rf node_modules.  
npm run setup
```

If the error still persists, try updating the **uuid** module. Run:

```
npm update uuid
```